# Short CAN Bus - Termination?

Tags: bus

How do you terminate a CAN Bus that is physically short (i.e. it stays on the same PCB, but has multiple transceivers connected to it). I would think I need one 60 ohms resistor, right?

Comment: Why bother using transceivers if it's just on the same PCB? You can just hook them up as a single ended wired-AND bus.

Comment: That's true, but I must have the option to extend this bus to another remote device. So I was wondering what the correct termination is if no remote device is connected.

Comment: For a short bus it should work without anything. But 120 Ohms at each end is the good way to do it.

Comment: If you extend to a remote device (how far?), the both ends of the bus need to be terminated with 120 ohms. So this device must have 120 ohms for this end of the bus, and perhaps an option for enabling and disabling a second 120 ohm terminator if there is no cable to remote device. Or have a connector which requires at least something plugged in, if nothing else, a connector with 120 ohm terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory both ends should have 120 ohms, and the PCB tracks should have 120 ohm impedance. Single 60 ohms might work just fine; that is how the electrical specs are measured.

Comment: I'm even more confused as the answer/comment from Dirk tells me that 60 ohms might not even work.

Answer (score 0):

No. A single 120 Ohm resistor works well.

Comment: But it won't have correct DC load if it's not 60 ohms?

Comment: A long CAN bus needs two resistors 120 ohms in parallel, so this translates to one 60 ohms resistor for a short bus, or is this wrong thinking?

Comment: @StefanWyss The transmitter wants to see an impedance of 120 Ohms. All I can say is that I did once try it with 60, but it didn't work.

Comment: @DirkBruere no the transmitter wants to see an impedance of 60 ohms, which is the impedance of a 120 ohm bus terminated to 120 ohms at both ends. If you have an infinitely long 120 ohm transmission line, and you connect a tranceiver at some point, it will have 120 ohms impedance to left and another 120 ohms impedance to right, which equals to load of 60 ohms.

Comment: @Justme I suggest you try it. It's easy enough